# Swift init ViewController from Xib file error

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

Using `Xcode 8.2` and `Swift 2.3`

I have a view controller files namVcc.swift and namVccUI.xib

I am trying to initialize the view controller from xib file but getting error

|*| Try 1 :

```
let namVccVar = UINib(nibName: "namVccUI", bundle:
    nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! namVcc

navigationController?.pushViewController(namVccVar, animated: true)
```

|*| Try 2 :

```
let namVccVar = namVcc(nibName: "namVccUI", bundle: nil)

navigationController?.pushViewController(namVccVar, animated: true)
```

> Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'namVccUI'

I also checked the properties of xib file > Target Membership and it's checked.

What else could be the problem?

Comment: The first one looks right.  Are you 100% sure the .xib is named 'namVccUI'?  And is it in the same bundle as the viewController you're trying to initialize it in?

Comment: Yes 100 % sure with the name and same bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting a similar but slightly differently worded error when I try to set this up. I get

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "namVccUI" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

when I just create an empty project with your code in `Try 2` and a new, clean .xib file. I had to explicitly set the Referencing Outlet of the UIView in the .xib file to the File's Owner and I had to ensure that the Custom Class of the File's Owner in the .xib was set to namVcc. I never could get `Try 1` to work.

Comment: Setting Custom Class of the File's Owner in the .xib was set to namVcc helped me

Comment: How did you 'explicitly set the Referencing Outlet of the UIView in the .xib file to the File's Owner'?

Comment: Draw the little line. Same as you would set any Referencing Outlet